# Stargazer Table does not calculate all descriptive values

Tags: html, r, markdown, stargazer

I produced a table using `stargazer`package and am wondering why not all descriptives can be calculated. The following generates the table:

```
stargazer(cont_data, digits = 1, digit.separator = ",", median = TRUE, font.size = "footnotesize", column.sep.width = "15pt",  type = 'html',
          title = "Summary statistics of continous variables")
```

The HTML of the table looks like follows:

```
<table style="text-align:center"><caption><strong>Summary statistics of continous variables</strong></caption>
<tr><td colspan="9" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Statistic</td><td>N</td><td>Mean</td><td>St. Dev.</td><td>Min</td><td>Pctl(25)</td><td>Median</td><td>Pctl(75)</td><td>Max</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="9" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Premiums Written in State</td><td>1,239,193</td><td>2,842.6</td><td>14,721.2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>119,776.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Cash and ST Investments to Liabilities</td><td>1,224,160</td><td>157.3</td><td>533.1</td><td>0.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>22.0</td><td>69.0</td><td>3,959.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Dividends Paid</td><td>1,154,272</td><td>-2,007.7</td><td>14,639.9</td><td>-134,015.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Overall Premiums Written</td><td>1,249,248</td><td>205,516.8</td><td>839,256.7</td><td>-502.0</td><td>999.8</td><td>6,627.0</td><td>49,196.5</td><td>6,821,454.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Loss Sensitive Contracts</td><td>1,248,968</td><td>577.0</td><td>4,304.1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>39,129.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Reinsurance Usage</td><td>1,248,576</td><td>98,974.9</td><td>431,161.7</td><td>-953.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2,082.5</td><td>17,572.0</td><td>3,386,686.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Reserves to Equity</td><td>1,151,808</td><td>5,896.1</td><td>13,428.8</td><td>0.0</td><td>33.0</td><td>89.0</td><td>229.0</td><td>45,108.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Total Assets</td><td>1,167,432</td><td>581,352.0</td><td>2,402,868.0</td><td>528.0</td><td>6,935.0</td><td>23,702.0</td><td>123,355.0</td><td>19,371,174.0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">States Active</td><td>936,208</td><td>7.2</td><td>13.3</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>5.0</td><td>55.0</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="9" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr></table>
```

This is it in HTML:
[image]

The summary of the `data.frame` looks like this:

```
str(cont_data)
'data.frame':   2091600 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Premiums Written in State             : int  0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA 0 0 ...
 $ Cash and ST Investments to Liabilities: int  1644 NA NA NA 3 NA NA NA 26 3 ...
 $ Dividends Paid                        : int  0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA 0 0 ...
 $ Overall Premiums Written              : int  62 NA NA NA 126127 NA NA NA 2997 146 ...
 $ Loss Sensitive Contracts              : int  0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA 0 0 ...
 $ Reinsurance Usage                     : int  0 NA NA NA 83435 NA NA NA 0 95 ...
 $ Reserves to Equity                    : int  0 NA NA NA 132 NA NA NA 51 100 ...
 $ Total Assets                          : int  2657 NA NA NA 502325 NA NA NA 10745 423027 ...
 $ States Active                         : int  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 54 ...
```

What can I do, to correct the "0"?

For the first variable I expect this for `min`:

```
> min(State_company$direct_premium_written)
[1] NA
> min(State_company$direct_premium_written, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] -68331
```

Why are they there?

I fail to produce an example with similar errors in the output.

Thanks a lot for any tip!

Comment: From the HTML table you posted, it looks like all the descriptives *have* been calculated. What are you expecting to see instead?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. edited the question accordingly. I suspect it may have to do with the NA but not sure

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand what the problem is. Are you able to share your source data? Or, at least, the `State_company$direct_premium_written` column? I suspect it is something to do with your dataset as I can't reproduce this with the in-built datasets in `stargazer`.

Comment: Sure. Let me try to make it available:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hB-tYeYPm4ner2JY2Zl7iyx6rgxg2-2q

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Yes, but when using your sample data, I get the correct min values!

Comment: I'm not really sure why the correct values aren't appearing for you, as I do get the correct min value when I use stargazer on your Sample.csv dataset. I can only suggest updating all your packages and checking your other columns. What happens when you try stargazer on just your Sample.csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205770/discussion-between-juan-and-meenaparam).

Comment: So, it seems this is due to the data set itself, or the packages installed